# jQuery datatable plugin with column visible option

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatables

I am working on a web page where I am using jQuery datatable plugin.

I am using "colvis" button to show/hide table columns.

I am facing a problem when I remove all columns(empty table after deselect all columns) and then select column(s) again. How to solve it? TIA.

[image]

***If there is at-least 1 column in the table then its working perfectly.**

No error on console as well.

```
  $(function () {           
            var table = $(".mydataTable").dataTable({            
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                bJQueryUI: true,
                "aLengthMenu": [[-1, 10, 20, 50, 100], ["All", 10, 20, 50, 100]],
    buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'colvis',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg"></i>',
                    collectionLayout: 'fixed one-column',
                    postfixButtons: ['colvisRestore']
                }
                ],
                dom: 'lfBrtip',
            });
```

Comment: Why not use `columns: ':gt(0)'` so the user cant hide the first column? Hiding all columns seems needless and counterproductive anyway. Imagine a "dont show any content"-feature in lets say Word :)

Comment: the problem was with some bootstrap classes which I have used for table I removed them and now its working..

Comment: It is perfectly OK if you answer your own question and accept it as an  answer. Perhaps it will help other people in the future.